# How can be give data to a table out of three tables in same class?

Tags: iphone

How can be give data to  a table out of three tables in same class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the delegate calls pass you the ID of the tableView along, so you can just retain the id of your table in an instance variable and probe for it in the delegate calls:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView == tableOne)
        return 1;
    else if (tableView == tableTwo)
        return 10;
}
```

Comment: Or you can combine the information using JOIN clauses in case you are talking about DataTables?